# How to override the previous defined PHP value via Ansible PHP role?

Tags: centos6, ansible, php.ini, provisioning, opcache

I'm trying to apply override PHP's `opcache.max_accelerated_files` setting via [geerlingguy's Ansible Role for PHP](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-php) onto [geerlingguy/centos6](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/geerlingguy/boxes/centos6)'s VM using the following lines (as part of provisioning script):

```
php_opcache_enabled_in_ini: false
php_opcache_enable_cli: 1
php_opcache_max_accelerated_files: "4096"
```

This seems to work (as `10-opcache.ini` is created in `/etc/php.d`) as:

```
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.max_accelerated_files=8192
```

however the option is still not overridden for PHP:

```
$ php -i | grep opcache.max_accelerated_files
opcache.max_accelerated_files => 4000 => 4000
```

This is because `opcache.ini` has already this settings set:

```
$ grep ^opcache.max_accelerated_files opcache.ini 
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
```

and somehow it takes precedence over `10-opcache.ini`.

I've tried to change default `php_opcache_conf_filename` to `opcache.ini`, but then `10-opcache.ini` got overridden and wiped out the previous content (including `zend_extension=opcache.so` line), so OPcache got disabled.

How do I change PHP setting using ansible role for PHP, so the setting is applied correctly which would override the previous value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's because `10-opcache.ini` is before `opcache.ini` in alphabetic order, which is relevant for load order. So the config of `opcache.ini` is the last one applied.

You can change the filename to something like `zzz-opcache.ini` or my prefered way add a `zzz-custom.ini` with all your custom configs in one file.

On the other hand, why would you have two files for opcache? can you combine them into one?

Comment: The `opcache.ini` was already provided with the VM box, `10-opcache.ini` was created by PHP ansible role. Logically `10-opcache.ini` should load first, but it doesn't happen for all settings.